# Regular expression in C#

Tags: asp.net, regex

I am trying to search and change all links in a html file I have.

so I want it to go throuhg and change `<a href="whatever"`
to `<a href="mynewlink"`

I can do it with visual studios find option using regular expression. But it keeps selecting too much of the string.

I have tried:  `<a href=".*"`

but the problem is it will get the entire string until the last " (so if there for example:

```
<a href="www.google.com.au" id="myId">
```

it will select all the way up to the end of `myID"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dot can also match a quote, and the asterisk makes it match as many characters as it can, so it'll match right past the end of the `href` attribute value.

Use `<a href="[^"]*"` instead. `[^"]` means "any character except quote", so it'll never match past the attribute value.